# Full text mysql database search in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-haystack

We have been using a MYSQL database for our project and Django as the backend framework. We want to support a full text search on a particular table and return the Queryset in Django. We know that Django supports full text search on a Postgres database but we can't move to another database now.

From what we have gathered till now -

1. Using inbuilt search functionality - Here we check on every field if the value exists and then take an OR to combine the results. Similar to the link ([Django Search query within multiple fields in same data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656210/django-search-query-within-multiple-fields-in-same-data-table)).

   This approach however straight forward may be inefficient for us because we have huge amounts of data.
2. Using a library or package - From what we have read Django haystack is something a lot of people are talking about when it comes to full text search.
   Django Haystack - https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#installation

We haven't checked the library completely yet because we are trying to avoid using any library for this purpose. Let us know if you people have worked with this and have any views.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks possible by getting a django migration to create the full text index and then having a custom model manager which adds the search function to the queryset. There's a blog post here; https://blog.confirm.ch/django-1-8-mysql-mariadb-full-text-search/

Comment: Hey @markwalker_, Thanks for your response. Will check the blog that you had sent